# Swift 3 - How do I implement an accordion-style layout?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.

I want to achieve something like the look below:

[image]

I want a view where I can have a top heading and label and an intro paragraph along with a line separator but have this "accordion" style layout where users can click to reveal/hide different parts of the information.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This question is a little broad, but I would suggest looking into `UITableView`. You might choose to implement a table view where each 'subject' (e.g. `Yearly Benefit Tracker`, `Questions?`) has its own section. The title cell is the first cell in its section, and when tapped it either inserts or removes a second cell containing the accordion content. For the top heading/content you can use `UITableView`'s header view feature.

Comment: A dropdown menu with stack views should be a good solution in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no actual accordion style layout in `UIKit`, there's no right answer, you'll just have to roll your own.

Here's how I've done it:

- Create a sectioned tableview, each collapsable group of
  information is it's own section. Each section should have a section header.  Implement viewForHeaderInSection.
- The header view could have a label that says 'Yearly Benefit Tracker', etc, and a disclosure image that changes based on whether the
  section is opened or closed, like in your example.
- Each section has a tap gesture recognizer associated with it.
- When a tap gesture is triggered, the corresponding function adds that section to a set of 'collapsed sections'
- Reload the table view
- When number of sections is called it still returns all the sections
- When number of rows is called check to see if that section is in the set of collapsed sections.  If it's collapsed, return 0 rows for that section.
- Implement the reverse for expanding.